# Закрыть teamviewer

Tags: iptables, firewall, teamviewer, linux

Добрый день господа,

Есть софт teamviewer. Полезный и нужный, но бесконтрольный. Хочется его закрыть дабы пользователи не пускали в сеть кого попало. У кого есть опыт?

p.s. Еще есть ammyy admin - тоже кандидат на закрытие.

Comment: p.s. "закрыть" - я имею в виду не удалить софт, а заблокировать на маршрутизаторе.

Answer (score 1):

Единого решения по сути нет. Нужны комплексные решения.

1. В `iptables` или на `маршрутере` который выпускает в мир заблокировать ip-adressa которые использует teamviewer. Актуального списока ip на данный момент нет, его можете самостоятельно получить просканив траффик утилитой типа `wireshark\tcpdump`
2. На клиентских машинах путем исправления файла hosts "подменить" обращение к домену сервиса на

   *.teamviewer.com 172.0.0.1

   *.dyngate.com 172.0.0.1

   *.verisign.com 172.0.0.1

Таким образом с вероятностью в 90% Вы закроете "дырку"

Answer (score 0):

Удалить через панель управления, uninstall закроет все порты которые он открывал, если не поможет то закрыть порты каким либо софтом 5938 (TCP, UDP), и 9997 для 5ой версии.